# Customize Bootstrap installed from npm

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, webpack

I am using webpack to require **Bootstrap**, so I install bootstrap from npm, but I also want to customize **Bootstrap** by modify 'variables.less', It cause a problem, the next time I upgrade **Bootstrap** from npm, my modification is gone, so what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

You can easily overwrite LESS variables in your own custom file outside of Bootstrap. As long as you @import the file with your Bootstrap variable overwrites after you @import all of the Bootstrap LESS files, you'll be fine.

Comment: I got a question. What about if you want to remove _typo.scss completely? Should I make an empty file _typo.scss or what? tnx

Comment: In the main bootstrap.less file that imports all of the others, you can remove or comment out the line that imports _typo.less.

Comment: do you mean in node_module? or where?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest editing files directly in node_modules since your edits will be overwritten any time you update that package.  But you can copy bootstrap.less from node_modules and put it in your site files to be imported from there (be sure to update the import paths within bootstrap.less since they're relative). Then you can control exactly which parts of bootstrap are imported or not.

Answer (score 4):

Building on [Shane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217190/customize-bootstrap-installed-from-npm/32265338#32265338), I did it this way:

- copy `node_modules/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less` to `boostrap-custom.less`
- *place that file in your source tree*, for example `src/style/bootstrap-custom.less`
- in the file, create a variable that points to bootstrap's `less` sources (that one is under `node_modules`), and search/replace all existing `@import` directives to point to correct path (see example below). Customize as needed.
- `require`/`import` that file where needed: `import './style/bootstrap-custom.less';`

Example (adapt relative path, comment out unwanted modules, do your customizations, etc):

```
/* Custom Bootstrap composer */

@BS: "../../node_modules/bootstrap/less";

// Core variables and mixins
@import "@{BS}/variables.less";
@import "@{BS}/mixins.less";

// Reset and dependencies
@import "@{BS}/normalize.less";
@import "@{BS}/print.less";
// Disabling glyphicons for [reasons]
//@import "@{BS}/glyphicons.less";
[...]
```

Variable interpolation in `@import` statements was [implemented in Less 1.4.0](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-import-statements), so nowadays it should be supported everywhere.

This should survive (minor) updates to bootstrap. Of course if they heavily change the main `.less` file you might need to adapt or redo it.